# Is there a more efficient way to apply the custom function text slicer to the entire dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataset

I have a dataset that looks similar to this containing MAC Addresses:

```
dataset = {'Col1': ['10:50:1C:56:FF:C1', np.nan, '56:20:30:70:10:00'], 'Col2': [np.nan, 
'50:60:40:10:00:00', np.nan]}
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data = dataset)

# Showing dataframe

    Col1               Col2
0   10:50:1C:56:FF:C1   NaN
1   NaN                50:60:40:10:00:00
2   56:20:30:70:10:00   NaN
```

I am looking to slice these addresses where it finds them into the first seven characters only, so the dataframe should look like this:

```
# Showing Sliced dataframe

    Col1               Col2
0   10:50:1C           NaN
1   NaN                50:60:40
2   56:20:30           NaN
```

Now I have written the below custom function that does the job successfully however it uses recursion, and I am looking for a method that can cut time and use less memory.

```
def sliceit(x):
  x = str(x)
  return x[:8]

def slice_macs(rowx):
  for i, item in enumerate(rowx):
     rowx[i] = sliceit(item)
  return rowx
```

I have also received wonderful responses from this community on a similar question I asked regarding slicing a different form of string , however, I tried looking into Regular Expressions and make alterations to the below so it can apply to these type of strings but I have had no luck.

```
IPs = splits.replace(r"(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\.\d+", r"\1", regex=True)
```

**So my Question, is there a way to accomplish the above in a much more pythonic and faster way without using so much memory?**

Comment: I don't see any recursion in your solution?

Comment: Hey Timus, the second function contains the first one. isn't that recursion?

Comment: No, it isn't. Recursion happens when a function calls _itself_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand correctly you can use the [pd.Series.str](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) as a vectorized method to use string slicing on the series.

```
dataframe.Col1 = dataframe.Col1.str[:8]
dataframe.Col2 = dataframe.Col2.str[:8]
```

Comment: Hey Bkeesey, unfortunately not because I do not know how many columns I will get. this is part of a larger report that takes an initial column with each cell containing one mac address OR several separated by commas. so after I expand into a new frame to work on them separately, I do not know beforehand how many columns it will expand to. (hope this makes sense). and thanks for taking the time to look into it!

Comment: @CatDad You can easily expand the solution into one that can deal with an arbitrary number of columns: `for col in dataframe.columns: dataframe[col] = dataframe[col].str[:8]`.

Comment: Hey Timus, I will try and do that and see what I get! thanks!